# Strong params ParameterMissing exception bubbling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

**EDIT** This should not be, so I re-checked my code and it works as expected now. I'm sorry.
**This question should be closed**

Trying to catch ParameterMissing exception in Rails 5.2 API app (params **did not include** `:user` hash)

```rb
    def create
      begin
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        render json: { user: user }, status: 201
      rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
        render json: { errors: { e.param => [e.message] } }, status: 422
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
        render json: { errors: e.record.errors }, status: 422
      rescue Exception => e
        render json: { errors: e }, status: 422
      end
    end

    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Log indicates the exception and no exception did caught

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
```

When changing `user_params` method to

```rb
  def user_params
    begin
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
      raise e
    end
  end
```

the exception gets caught in `create` method

When changing user creation line to

```rb
  user = User.create!(params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation))
```

the exception gets caught too.

So the question is: why the first code don't work?

Comment: In your params getting sent over to the controller, the values are likely not inside a user object.  It should look like this `:user => {values, values, etc}` but it probably doe snot.  Can you post your form code and an example of the params getting sent to the controller on form submit.

Comment: @RockwellRice I've made some mistake somewhere. I re-checked these examples and it work as expected, I'm sorry. This question should be closed, but I don't have enough reputation so I've edited it. As for the initial task, the `:user` hash was deliberately missed for API testing purposes.